# A simple C# Statement works unexpected

Tags: c#, line, division, multiplication

I've got this line of code:

```
int WStoneCost = PriceMethod.StoneCost / 100 * AP;
```

While PriceMethod.StoneCost is equal to 25 and AP is equal to 70. 
I've checked it using breakpoints and I can't understand why do I get zero after I run this line. (WStoneCost is equal to zero) 
Is it just a wrong symbol or am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.
And how to get a correct double at the end? Like 17.**5**

Comment: Maybe some of your variables are integers instead of floating point. `(int)(25 / 100)` equals 0.

Comment: @JonathanWood: I'd say there's 100% chance of that.

Comment: All of them are integers. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Also worth noting that order of operations is worth looking at.  I think you want is `(25/100) * 70` which is `17.5`, but what you've shown is equivalent to `25 / (100*70)` (because multiply has priority over divide), which is `.00347...`

Comment: @paqogomez No, the `*` and `/` operators are applied left-to-right, so it's equivalent to `(25/100) * 70`

Comment: @paqogomez - Does it really give precedence to multiply over divide?  When I run this line of code:  `double WStoneCost = 25.0 / 100.0 * 70;`  The result is 17.5.  My understanding is that multiply and divide have equal precedence and are therefore executed in the order that they appear from left to right.  (D Stanley beat me to it!).

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: You are correct; note that for your statement to be true the operators must have equal precedence **and be left-associative**. Since both multiplication and division are left-associative, you're all set.

Comment: `PriceMethod.StoneCost` and `WStoneCost` should both be of type `decimal`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing integer division, so `25/100` is `0`, not `0.25`, and hence `0 * 70` is `0`.  Since your result variable is also an `int` it's unclear what result you are expecting, but you could reorder the operations to get a non-zero answer:

```
int WStoneCost = (PriceMethod.StoneCost * AP)/ 100 ;
```

It's still integer division, but with your inputs will divide 25*70 (1,750) by 100, which will give you 17.

If you want a <strike>floating-point</strike> decimal result, just use `100m`:

```
decimal WStoneCost = (PriceMethod.StoneCost * AP)/ 100m ;
```

Since the literal `100m` is a `decimal`, then the compiler will use <strike>floating-point</strike> decimal division, which will give you a `decimal` result.

Comment: Please **never** recommend that people use `double` for financial calculations. Use `decimal`, always.

Comment: @EricLippert good point - I've amended my answer to return a `decimal` instead.

Comment: What's the difference between them?

Comment: `double` can have rounding errors since many floating-point numbers (like 0.1) can't re represented _exactly_ in binary form.  `decimal` uses a different storage mechanism so it _can_ represent 0.1 exactly, and so calculations are more accurate.

Comment: @ArasTeam: `decimal` is larger, slower, and represents decimal numbers; that is, numbers that are fractions of a power of ten. `double` is smaller, faster, and represents numbers which are fractions of a power of two. Since 0.01 = 1 / 100 is a fraction with a power of ten, not a fraction with a power of two, it can be accurately represented in a decimal but not in a double.

Answer (score 4):

> And how to get a correct double at the end? Like 17.5

Your question and both of the two answers given so far indicate that all three of you want to do something dangerously wrong.  **You are doing financial calculations so you should always be using `decimal`, never `double`.** `double` is for *physics* calculations, not *financial* calculations.

Comment: Unless you need to do an "exotic" operation like a power, square root, or log- then you'll likely have to convert back to `double` anyways since .NET has no overloads for decimals with those operations. I think saying "always" is way too strong of a prescription. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @MgSam: Sure; but if you're doing a square root then odds are good that your computation does not need to have zero error in decimal in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with JonathanWood. According to the values that you provided, your answer is going to produce a fractional number. Therefore, you need WStoneCost to be a double or a float. Also, you might want to use partentheses in your equations to ensure that the order of operations is carried out to your expectations.

Hope this helps!

-Gary The Bard

Comment: Just changing the variable type to `double` will not change the resulting value - it will still use integer division, but will then cast the `int` 0 to a `double` 0.

Comment: I had to set 100 to 100.0 that it would be a double but thanks anyway.

Comment: Please **never** recommend that people use `double` for financial calculations. Use `decimal`, always.